# Python: How do you decorate methods in child classes using a method in the parent class?

Tags: python, class, oop, decorator

code example:

```
class Parent:
    # something here that says that the function "foo" always starts in print("bar")

class Son(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        pass

class Daughter(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        print("q")


Son().foo() # prints "bar"
Daughter().foo() # prints "bar" then "q"
```

i tried to use `@super.func` though it's shoddy to copy paste that in every class that has `Parent` as the parent and has the `foo` method. any elegant solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be more elegant methods, but you can decorate the methods of the subclasses in the `__init_subclass__` hook

```py
def bar_printer(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('bar')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


class Parent:

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls.foo = bar_printer(cls.foo)


class Son(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        pass


class Daughter(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        print("q")

son = Son()
daughter = Daughter()

son.foo()
daughter.foo()
```

Output:

```
bar
bar
q
```